# _xsrf argument missing from POST in AWS EMR notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I got following error while attaching kernel to my EMR Jupyter notebook.
"**_xsrf argument missing from POST**"
I tried to detached and attached the cluster but didn't solve my problem.